# Glue PySpark - Fixed Width File Processing and Validation

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue, fixed-width

I have to validate Fixed Width files that I am reading from S3 to Glue.
I have the lengths of each column and I have to write a glue job to validate these files.

How do I efficiently check the lengths of every row to filter out the records which don't have the correct `total_length`?

What is the best way to read such files?

I tried reading it as CSV into one `col0` in the Dynamic Frame and tried to filter out `length` using `FILTER` but this gives me a dictionary

```
bad_length_DF = dynamicFramerawtxt.filter(lambda x: len(x['col0']) != total_row_len)
```

How do I remove the records from my Dynamic Frame that have wrong lengths and create a an `ERROR_Dynamic` frame?

Answer (score 2):

My general recommendation is to use Spark dataframe instead of Glue dynamicframe unless you need to use the built-in transformations ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-_transforms)) or Glue job bookmark ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html)).

Below is a complete PySpark script for your scenario.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import length
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


data = [
    {"col0": "0123456789"},
    {"col0": "01234567890"}
]
total_length = 10

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df_bad = df.filter(length(df.col0)!=total_length)
df_good = df.filter(length(df.col0)==total_length)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Dynamic Frame then you can use it like below. But the column type must be string.

```py
from awsglue.transforms import *


raw_dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options= {'paths':f"s3://<bucket_name>/<subfolders>/"]},
    format="<data_type>")
good_length_dyf = Filter.apply(frame=raw_dyf, f=lambda x:len(x['<column_name>']) == total_row_len)
bad_length_dyf = Filter.apply(frame=raw_dyf, f=lambda x:len(x['<column_name>']) != total_row_len)
```

Thanks.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer...In my specific case, we are not using Glue Catalog. I have to directly read using from_options.

Comment: Just updated my answer.